# Creating Canvas Directive in AngularJS with FontAwesome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

I am trying to create a directive that uses font awesome. My goal is to be able to control the canvas font size through my controller via $scope but the font awesome icons don't render.

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('customButtonCanvas', ['$document', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      width : '=',
      height : '=',
      options : '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element){

      var ctx = element[0].getContext('2d');
      ctx.font = "40px FontAwesome";
      ctx.fillText("\uf000", 120, 120);

    }
  };

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the code, it turns out that the DOM was NOT loaded yet. Since the DOM was not ready yet this means the FontAwesome CSS was not ready either. This is why it did NOT render.

To solve the problem, I injected a $timeout dependency. This way the directive can fire after the DOM is ready!

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('customButtonCanvas', ['$timeout', function (timer) {
    /* Note the injection of the $timeout service allows us to 
     * Wait until the DOM is ready then fire our directive!
     */
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          width : '=',
          height : '=',
          options : '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            var startCanvas = function(){
                var ctx = element[0].getContext('2d');
                ctx.font = "40px FontAwesome";
                ctx.fillText("\uf069", 120, 120);
            };

            //Lets run this directive after dom is ready
            timer(startCanvas, 0);
            // It works even with a delay of 0s
        }
    }   
}]);
```

Comment: I have to ask you :
Where do you call for angular in your code ?
and where do you call for FA ?